# Any connection between -dom (kingdom) and dharma?

Tags: etymology

Appreciated the article on the derivation of -dom as in kingdom; any relationship between that and dharma? I see that -dom goes back to Old English for doom, judgment, law statute, and dharma goes back to Proto-Indo-Iranian root *dhar- ("to fasten, to support, to hold") (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharma), but was wondering if OE traces back to that as well.

Comment: While the initial consonant could be a match, there is no relationship between /r/ and /m/ in the history of English. See also etymonline: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=dharma&searchmode=none

Comment: EtymOnline: Old English dom "law, judgment,
condemnation," from Proto-
Germanic *domaz, ...
from PIE root *dhe- (cf. Sanskrit
dhaman- "law," Greek themis "law ....),
literally "to set, put"

Comment: -dom < Old English _dom_ (rel. to Old Saxon _-dum_ and Old High German _-tum_), judgement, authority < IE base _*dhom-_ (whence also Old Indian _dhaman-_, Gk _thomos_, heap, _themeilea_, foundation, _themis_, law, right, decree and Lithuanian _dome_, attention), (an enlargement of base _*dho-_, _*dhe-_, to put, place).

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be no relationship between *-dom* and *dharma.* There is, however, a definite etymological connection between *-dom* and *dhama*, as well as *dhaman* (the middle *a* is pronounced as [-aa-], as in *father*, in the case of these latter two sanskrit words).

The Sanskrit word ***dhaman*** literally means dwelling-place, house, abode, domain. By extension it is rarely taken to mean *law, rule or order*  but is etymologically distinct from *dharma*. It is cognate with the German *tuom*, Greek *themis*, Latin *fam-ulus* and Anglosaxon *dom*. The Proto-Germanic cognate is *domaz*, originating from the PIE root *dhe* meaning placing, putting, holding, possessing, having.

Sanskrit ***dharma*** means that which is established or firm, steadfast – and is derived from *dhara* and the PIE root *dhri* meaning bearing, supporting (soil, the world - and therefore earth, womb). This word does not have a [cognate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE) in the English Language, Greek or Latin.

[Monier-Williams]

Just as the German word ***sittlichkeit***, related in meaning to *dharma* somewhat, does not have a direct link to any corresponding English word.